# speed up copyto another Google sheets

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, get, getvalue

I have a code which copies row if condition.
By the source sheet is around 8 000 lines and the script fails because is too long.

How can I speed it up?

I would like it takes one 1 hr max.

I think it makes too many calls to Google. I hope we can reduce them.

```
function  dispacthtosheets()  { 
var  sSheet  =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');

var  srcSheet  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "Dispatch" );
var  lastRow  =  srcSheet.getLastRow ();***emphasized text***
for  ( var  i  =  1 ;  i  <=  lastRow ;  i ++ )  {
var  cellule  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "L"  +  i );
var  val  =  cellule.getValue();
if  ( val  ==  "Changement ENT" )  {
  var  tarSheet3  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "Changement ENT" );
  var  srcRange  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "C"  +  i  +  ":R" +  i  );
  var  tarRow3   =  tarSheet3.getLastRow (); 
  var  tarRange3 =  tarSheet3.getRange ( "C"  +  tarRow3  +  ":R"  +  tarRow3);
  srcRange.copyTo (tarRange3);
  tarSheet3.insertRowAfter ( tarRow3 ); 
  }    if ( val  ==  "VC en REL" )  {
      var  tarSheet1  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "VC en REL" );
      var  srcRange  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "C"  +  i  +  ":R" +  i  );
      var  tarRow1  =  tarSheet1.getLastRow (); 
      var  tarRange1  =  tarSheet1.getRange ( "C"  + tarRow1  +  ":R"  + tarRow1);
      srcRange.copyTo (tarRange1);
      tarSheet1.insertRowAfter ( tarRow1 );
  }    if  ( val  ==  "Solo à étudier" )  {
          var  tarSheet2  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "Solo à étudier" );
          var  srcRange  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "C"  +  i  +  ":R" +  i  );
          var  tarRow2   =  tarSheet2.getLastRow (); 
          var  tarRange2 =  tarSheet2.getRange ( "C"  +  tarRow2 +  ":R"  +  tarRow2);
          srcRange.copyTo (tarRange2);
          tarSheet2.insertRowAfter ( tarRow2 );
  }  if ( val  ==  "VC + 6 mois" )  {
            var  tarSheet4  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "VC + 6 mois" );
            var  srcRange  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "C"  +  i  +  ":R" +  i  );
            var  tarRow4  =  tarSheet4.getLastRow (); 
            var  tarRange4  =  tarSheet4.getRange ( "C"  + tarRow4  +  ":R"  + tarRow4);
            srcRange.copyTo (tarRange4);
            tarSheet4.insertRowAfter ( tarRow4);
  }    if  ( val  ==  "Sortie Nat" )  {
                var  tarSheet5  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "Sortie Nat" );
                var  srcRange  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "C"  +  i  +  ":R" +  i  );
                var  tarRow5  =  tarSheet5.getLastRow (); 
                var  tarRange5  =  tarSheet5.getRange ( "C"  + tarRow5  +  ":R"  + tarRow5);
                srcRange.copyTo (tarRange5);   
                tarSheet5.insertRowAfter ( tarRow5 );
  }    if  ( val  ==  "ZCTM" )  {
                    var  tarSheet6  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "ZCTM" );
                    var  srcRange  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "C"  +  i  +  ":R" +  i  );
                    var  tarRow6  =  tarSheet6.getLastRow (); 
                    var  tarRange6  =  tarSheet6.getRange ( "C"  + tarRow6  +  ":R"  + tarRow6);  
                    srcRange.copyTo (tarRange6);
                    tarSheet6.insertRowAfter ( tarRow6 );
  }   if  ( val  ==  "Appro validée" )  {
                        var  tarSheet7  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "Appro validée" );
                        var  srcRange  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "C"  +  i  +  ":R" +  i  );;
                        var  tarRow7  =  tarSheet7.getLastRow (); 
                        var  tarRange7  =  tarSheet7.getRange ( "C"  + tarRow7  +  ":R"  + tarRow7);
                        srcRange.copyTo (tarRange7);
                        tarSheet7.insertRowAfter ( tarRow7 );
  }   if  ( val  ==  "F943" )  {
                        var  tarSheet8  =  sSheet.getSheetByName ( "F943" );
                        var  srcRange  =  srcSheet.getRange ( "C"  +  i  +  ":R" +  i  );
                        var  tarRow8  =  tarSheet8.getLastRow (); 
                        var  tarRange8  =  tarSheet8.getRange ( "C"  + tarRow8  +  ":R"  + 
           tarRow8);
                        srcRange.copyTo (tarRange8);
                        tarSheet8.insertRowAfter ( tarRow8 );
                        }                                                                            
   sSheet.toast(' VC dispacthé !', 'Confirmation ');
}
};
```

Comment: You must limit the dialogue between the script and the sheets, download the data at once, and then process the data in the script. Post a link on a minimal spreadsheet. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your answer. Here a light copy of my sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lyC05CWYEOC8vjoLyN5kNfFo_CRJUpIAbLo5HCrYZPE/edit?usp=sharing . I'm not sure what i can do with your link to google guide. thank you

Comment: I'm French too, bienvenue. I will have a look soon, just to the function `dispacthtosheets`, but I have to well understand your complex sheet beforewards.

Comment: Super ! je dispatche les lignes vers les feuilles en fonction de la colonne L qui est ma condition. Great, i dispatch lines to sheets based on value in culomn L. Thank you

Comment: I can't find the tab `VC déjà présent`

Comment: it's a formula. If VC déjà présent, no copy.

Answer (score 0):

Archive for a complete sheet at once

```
function archiver(){
  var feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var archive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Archive");
  var data = feuille.getRange('A2:AC'+(feuille.getLastRow()-1)).getValues()
  var archiveData = []
  var lignes = []
  var ligne = 1
  try{
    data.forEach(function(row){
      ligne++
      if (row[28]) {
        archiveData.push(row)
        lignes.push(ligne)
      }
    })
    archive.getRange(archive.getLastRow()+1,1,archiveData.length,archiveData[0].length).setValues(archiveData)
    lignes.reverse().forEach(x => feuille.deleteRow(x));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Ligne(s) archivée(s) !', 'Fin de script ️')
    }catch(e){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Rien à archiver !', 'Fin de script ️')
    }
}
```

Comment: Génial ! c'est ça que je cherchais ! Un grand merci (again).

Comment: Salut Mike, je suis vraiment désolé. J'espère que tu vas bien. Encore merci pour tout.